# Compare two columns if another two columns are matching in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare two columns in excel if another two columns are matching.

```
A          B            C            D
$10      1234D          $40          100D
$20      1235D          $10          1234D 
$30       122D          $20          1235D 
$40      1222D          $30          1222D
```

First I need to compare col A and C If any matches find in col C then I need to compare B and D are matching. Example I have $10 in A and its ID is 1234D.i need to compare the same value in C. If I found $10 in C but its id is not 1234D I need to show that un matching one in another column.

I can match A and C as below .but I'm confusing on how to compare B and D after that?i'm new to excel vba and appreciate if any one help me to do this.

```
  Function Find_Matches()
  Dim CompareRange As Variant, SelectionRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    ' compare the selection.
     Sheets("Menu").Activate
    Set SelectionRange = Range("A2:A6")
    Set CompareRange = Range("C2:C6")

    ' Loop through each cell in the selection and compare it to
    ' each cell in CompareRange.
    For Each x In SelectionRange
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 4) = True

        Next y
    Next x

End Function
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a Macro and not a formula? 

Simple formula:
`=IF(AND(IF(A2=C2, TRUE, FALSE), IF(B2=D2, TRUE, FALSE), TRUE, FALSE))`

Then just drag the formula down as needed.

Also if you need to compare multiple rows, consider using `VLOOKUP`

Comment: thanks but I need to do it in vba.

Comment: what the result should be? You want just to wirte `True`/`False` in column E?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use vba any way.

Use this macro:

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Sheets("Menu").Range("A2:A6")

    With rng.Offset(, 4) ' write result in column E
        .FormulaArray = "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(" & rng.Address & "&""|""&" & _
            rng.Offset(, 1).Address & "," & rng.Offset(, 2).Address & _
            "&""|""&" & rng.Offset(, 3).Address & ",0))"
        .Calculate
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

it writes result (`True` or `False` in column `E`).

**Explanation:**

1. The main idea is to determine result with formula and then rewrite formula with its result value.
2. What we do is writing in `E2:E6` array formula
   `=ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$6 & "|" & $B$2:$B$6,$C$2:$C$6 & "|" & $D$2:$D$6,0))` - it returns `True` if we found, say `A2` and `B2` in any row of range `C2:D6`, e.g. `C3` and `D3`.
3. `.Value = .Value` part rewrites formulas with theirs results
4. How it works? Formula concatenates columns `A` and `B` and searches result in concatenation of columns `C` and `D`.
5. Why we're using `& "|" &` in formula? Imagine following situaltion:

---

```
A          B            C            D
$101      234D          $10          1234D
```

technically, concatenation of `A1 & B1` and `C1 & D1` gives you the same result: `$101234D`, but we clearly see that there is no match. That's why I'm using `|` as delimeter when concatenating values: `A1 & "|" & B1` returns `$101|234D` and `C1 & "|" & D1` returns `$10|1234D` and they are not the same, as we need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but if I want to write value of D in column E(instead of true or false)then how can I change this?

Comment: For `True` its clear what to returns, but what you'd like to return for `False`? In that case nothing found and what should be returned?

Answer (score 0):

1. Does it **need** to be in vba?   2.  What do you do to show there is a match or half-match?

Create a new column in F that is a concatenation of A & B.  Do the same in column G to concatenate the values in C & D.

Then use a formula that uses VLookup to see if looking up the concatenation of A & B returns an 'N/A' error.  If this is false, you have a matching column.

So, the formula for F2 is

```
'=concatenate(A2, B2)'
```

the formula for G2 is

```
'=concatenate(C2, D2)'
```

and the formula to do your vlookup is

```
'=IF(ISNA(Vlookup(concatenate(a2, b2), $F$2:$G$<LastRowOfData>, 2, FALSE)), "", "Matches")
```

If it needs to be in vba, you could set up a macro to perform these steps.

Comment: thanks for the idea. i'll use vba to concatenate columns and then will try to match.I need to use vba any way.