# Compare two columns with two other columns, and find matches as well as non-matches

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to figure out how to loop through two arrays, compare all values in the second array to all the values in the first array, and for each match, test whether the value in the same row, in Column D and Column H, are equal.

In my first array I have data like this:

[image]

In my second array, I have data like this:

[image]

So, for the OW cells, I want to compare

OW & Reporting Entity, and make sure both are VARCHAR.  This would be a match of the same data type for these field names.  Also, for OW & Currency, both are VARCHAR, so again, match.  For OW & CID_CounterpartyID, I see Integer and VARCHAR, so this is not a match, an I want to be aware of this.

I tried to put something together to do this, and I'm displaying my code below, but this definitely does not work.

```
Sub CompareFinal()

    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    ' All Rows in First Array
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Validation")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set r1 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    End With

    ' All rows in Second Array
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Validation")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Set r2 = .Range("E2:E" & lastrow)
    End With

    ' Loop through Second Array, which will bequual to or longer than First Array
    For Each cell In r2
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell, r1, 0)) Then
            cell.Offset(, 5) = "Match"
        Else
            cell.Offset(, 5) = "NoMatch"
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I'm sure I'm over-simplifying things in the code, and this is giving me incorrect results.  How can I get this straightened out?  Either a non-code function, or a VBA solution would do the job, I think.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Just looking at what you say you want to do... =D1=H1 (non-VBA) would output True/False for the same row having the same value in columns D and H.  That would be the simplest way I can think... I do that a lot for conditional format, rather than having a column dedicated to True/False.  Would need to dive more deeply into the format comparison.

Comment: I just posted the code.  Forgot to include that in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I actually need to match one two more columns.  The function below seems to do what I want.

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2 & "|" & C2 & "|" &D2,$E$2:$E$800 & "|" & $H$2:$H$800 & "|" & $I$2:$I$800,0))
```

I found this link to be very helpful.

[Compare two columns if another two columns are matching in excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978075/compare-two-columns-if-another-two-columns-are-matching-in-excel-macro)

Hope this helps others.