# How to get distinct values from col A by referring to highest timestamp from col B

Tags: excel, vba

I will have 125K to 150K rows which I want to paste in MS EXCEL and do some manual validations on it.

The sheet will have data like(but 125K to 150K rows):
[image: SampleDataSheet]

What I want is for each distinct value of ID_1 (say 1) find only that row where UTC_TIMESTAMP is highest. So for 1, the highest UTC_TIMESTAMP is "24-JUL-17 03.41.36.000000000 PM +00:00". Then Mark this row by adding 1 in new column FLAG. I want to do same for each distinct value of ID_1 (in this case 1, 303, 1461)

So the resulting sheet should look like:
[image: SampleREsultSheet]

Can this be done using excel(macro) or any other Microsoft Office tool?

Some additional details:
Please note that the highest UTC_TIMESTAMP will not always be the first row for each ID_1.

Format of all the cells including UTC_TIMESTAMP is General but I can change the format if it could help.

Comment: I would start by figuring out how to convert the UTC timestamp into something Excel can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link in the following URL:

[Compare two columns with two other columns, and find matches as well as non-matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285711/compare-two-columns-with-two-other-columns-and-find-matches-as-well-as-non-matc)

I think that will answer several of your questions.  Post back with additional questions, or start a brand new link!!